# What do you call a title that conceals a pun?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was reading the clive barker book "Mister B Gone" and it is obviously a pun or some such name for "Mister be gone" as in "sir, go away". I got to thinking about this and this is actually fairly common way of doing things in titles or names. "I P. Freely" is a old simpsons joke.

Is there a name for this kind of pun? Where you hide a sentence inside a title?

Comment: The closest specific thing I've been able to find for this use so far is a homophonic pun, where the pun is formed by using words which sound like something else ("Atheism is a non-prophet institution" for example)

Comment: I'd call it a "punny title" (though a poor one).

Comment: Not to pick nits, but "I. P. Freely" predates The Simpsons by many years!

Comment: For an ongoing delight, listen to [*Car Talk's* regular end of show credits](http://www.cartalk.com/content/staff-credits) (now in reruns). We miss them sorely.

Comment: I prefer my puns intended.

Comment: @bib: You may remember the old Prairie Home Companion bit that had Neil Dupré and Xavier Onassis.

Comment: In English, there's no special word for this. It's just 'a title with a pun'

Comment: @JohnClifford Aren't puns in general formed using homophones?

Comment: @Barmar - Dunno about that, but they are often quite gay.

Comment: @Barmar Not necessarily. There are other forms of pun that don't rely on homophones.

Comment: @JohnClifford Dictionaries disagree on whether homophones have to be spelled differently (i.e. distinguishing them from homographs). By the more liberal definition, puns necessarily involve homophones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a real person has a name that is especially well suited or descriptive, it is called an *[aptronym](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/aptronym)* (or *aptonym*)

> A person’s name that is regarded as amusingly appropriate to their occupation:
>   *he began collecting aptronyms when he saw an ad for a flower shop operated by Flora Gardner*

Also *euonym*

> An appropriate or well-chosen name; (formerly in technical use) a name that conforms to the requirements of a particular system of nomenclature.
>   The term was popularized by its appearance as the winning word in the 1997 U.S. National Spelling Bee competition.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

A long list of such real names is found in this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptronym) article.

The fanciful versions seem to be a logical extension.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [**punny**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/punny)

> constituting or involving a pun

Or in informal contexts, [**puntastic**](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/puntastic)